# Dependency is not satisfiable libgcrypt11 when instaing a software on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-15.04, staruml

I'm trying to install starUML on ubuntu 15.04 but I always have this message

> "Dependency is not satisfiable libgcrypt11 (>=1.4.5)"

Could someone help me!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download [libgcrypt11 (1.5.4-2ubuntu1.1)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic-updates/libs/libgcrypt11) and install it. There is some [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgcrypt11/+bug/1452216) in Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 4):

Try to download and install [libgcrypt11 (1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/libgcrypt11), as it's the latest version available.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (it worked for me in Ubuntu 15.10 64bit)

```
wget ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u3_amd64.deb
```